# ./configure results in bootstrapping make fragment error only on github

Tags: c++, docker, github, compiler-errors, github-actions

I have a docker container build from debian:latest. The Dockerfile configures and makes the project the project. This build works on local and builds a container. However on github it gives me the following error:

```
[1/2] STEP 16/17: RUN ./configure GIT_BRANCH=$BRANCH GIT_VERSION=$VERSION
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... (cached) yes
checking for g++... g++
checking whether the C++ compiler works... yes
checking for C++ compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking whether make supports the include directive... yes (GNU style)
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C99... none needed
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 3145728
checking how to convert x86_64-pc-linux-gnu file names to x86_64-pc-linux-gnu format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert x86_64-pc-linux-gnu file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for dlltool... no
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for ar... ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... @
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for a working dd... /bin/dd
checking how to truncate binary pipes... /bin/dd bs=4096 count=1
checking for mt... no
checking if : is a manifest tool... no
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking for ld used by g++... /usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) is GNU ld... yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking for g++ option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if g++ PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if g++ static flag -static works... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... (cached) GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether g++ supports C++14 features with -std=c++14... yes
checking for boostlib >= 1.42.0... yes
checking whether the Boost::Regex library is available... yes
checking for exit in -lboost_regex... yes
checking for sphirewall-libs... configure: We could not detect the sphirewall libraries.
checking for ldap_simple_bind_s in -lldap... yes
checking for pthread_create in -lpthread... yes
checking for curl_global_init in -lcurl... yes
checking for sys/types.h... (cached) yes
checking for netinet/in.h... yes
checking for arpa/nameser.h... yes
checking for netdb.h... yes
checking for resolv.h... yes
checking whether to enable assertions... yes
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for libprocps... yes
checking that generated files are newer than configure... done
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating src/Makefile
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating src/autoconf.h
config.status: executing depfiles commands
config.status: error: in `/sphirewall-code/sphirewall-core':
config.status: error: Something went wrong bootstrapping makefile fragments
    for automatic dependency tracking.  If GNU make was not used, consider
    re-running the configure script with MAKE="gmake" (or whatever is
    necessary).  You can also try re-running configure with the
    '--disable-dependency-tracking' option to at least be able to build
    the package (albeit without support for automatic dependency tracking).
See `config.log' for more details
[2/2] STEP 1/10: FROM debian:latest
error building at STEP "RUN ./configure GIT_BRANCH=$BRANCH GIT_VERSION=$VERSION": error while running runtime: exit status 1
time="2023-01-12T15:41:50Z" level=error msg="exit status 1"
Error: Error: buildah exited with code 1
```

I expect my github action to build a container out of this. I have attached my docker file too. I also wish I could see the config.log that github generates. Is there a way to do that?

Docker file:

```
#Taking base as bookworm version and naming it builder
FROM debian:latest as builder

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

#Libraries needed
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install build-essential apt-utils\
                    libprocps-dev\
                    iproute2\
                    g++\
                    libcurl4-openssl-dev\
                    libdumbnet-dev\
                    libjemalloc-dev\
                    libpam0g-dev\
                    libldap2-dev\
                    libpcap-dev\
                    libevent-dev\
                    libnfnetlink-dev\
                    libmnl-dev\
                    ldap-utils\
                    libnetfilter-queue-dev\
                    uuid-dev\
                    libtool\
                    libncurses5\
                    libncurses5-dev\
                    libboost-dev\
                    libgtest-dev\
                    libboost-regex-dev\
                    openssl\
                    libssl-dev\
                    automake\
                    libboost-thread-dev\
                    libboost-system-dev\
                    libsqlite3-dev\
                    libboost-serialization-dev\
                    libboost-random-dev\
                    libboost-iostreams-dev\
                    procps\
                    libnetfilter-conntrack-dev\
                    libpstreams-dev\
                    kmod\
                    vim\
                    iptables\
                    pkg-config

COPY fz-pkgrepo_1.0_amd64.deb /tmp
RUN dpkg -i /tmp/fz-pkgrepo_1.0_amd64.deb
RUN apt-get update

COPY sphirewall.conf /etc/sphirewall.conf
RUN mkdir sphirewall-code
COPY ../sphirewall-code sphirewall-code/
WORKDIR /sphirewall-code/sphirewall-core

#Make the sphirewalld service inside
RUN ls
RUN autoreconf -ivf
RUN ./configure
RUN make
```

Comment: Please use the "Edit" link and fix the formatting of your question.  Use Code Blocks to format code and output, not block quoting.  Quoting will refill all the text.  If you look at the preview window for your question you can see what it will look like to people reading it.  Please spend a minute or two making it easily readable, since you're asking many people to read it and help you for free.

Comment: Well, I see the error message `./configure: line 20431: git: command not found`.  It sounds pretty clear to me: you haven't installed `git` into your docker image.  Where's the confusing part?

Comment: Thanks for looking. I did manage to get rid of git errors. However it fails at the same configure error. I have updated the logs in the question

Comment: The next set of errors I see is: `checking for sphirewall-libs... configure: We could not detect the sphirewall libraries.` so it looks like those are missing.  Also it says: `See 'config.log' for more details` did you look there to see what exactly failed?  I don't think we have enough information to actually solve the problem, all we can do is point out error messages in the output, which you can probably see for yourself :-/  But, we can't help you find out why those error messages are happening.

Comment: I have mentioned in question, this is github actions. Can you help me know where is config.log generated in gitub actions because when I download logs after a run, I can't find it.

Comment: Sorry, I don't use GitHub much and I've never used GitHub actions.  But if your question is about how to debug GitHub actions and Google can't help you, maybe you need to ask a new question, or add a new tag to this question to draw the attention of people who know about that.